# Exemplo de Pool de Thread em delphi

Tags: delphi, thread, threadpool

Como faço um `pool` de `Thread`, preciso executar um processo que contém vários registros, porém preciso enviar por demanda, enviar 10 e na medida que for liberando, vai enviando mais.... como posso fazer ?

Montei um exemplo...

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
   MinhaThread = class(TThread)
   procedure Execute; override;
   procedure Verifica;
   procedure Fechar;
   Private
   constructor Create();
end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    thread: MinhaThread;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure consultaProcesso(Sender: TObject);
    procedure postJSON(JSON:String);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  I : Integer;
  JSON:String;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ MinhaThread }

constructor MinhaThread.Create;
begin
inherited
  Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  Priority := tpLower;
  Resume;
end;

procedure MinhaThread.Execute;
Var Sender : TObject;
begin
   Synchronize(Verifica);
   Form1.consultaProcesso(Sender); // Executar Rotina ( Procedures )

   while not Terminated do
    begin
        Sleep (10);
        Terminate; // Finaliza a Thread
        Synchronize(Fechar);
    end;

end;

procedure MinhaThread.Fechar;
begin
  //application.terminate;
end;

procedure MinhaThread.Verifica;
begin
  Form1.Caption := 'EXECUTANDO...'+IntToStr(I);
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  thread := MinhaThread.Create();
end;

procedure TForm1.consultaProcesso(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //exemplo com o for
  // porem aqui eu percorro a query, passo 
  // para a variavel JSON o json que está na query
  // e chamo o metodo post
  for I := 0 to 100 do
    begin
      postJSON(JSON);
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.postJSON(JSON: String);
begin
  //faz um post pelo idHTTP;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(DateTimeToStr(now)+ ' - Executando JSON '+IntToStr(I));
  //para simular um tempo de espera do retorno
  Sleep(1000);
  //retorno...
  Memo1.Lines.Add(DateTimeToStr(now)+ ' - Retorno JSON '+IntToStr(I));
end;

end.
```

No método `consultaProcesso` coloquei um `for`, mas seria o mesmo que o `while` que faço na `query` pegando o `JSON` e passando para o metodo `postJSON`, nesse método coloquei um `sleep` para simular um tempo de retorno que tenho do `post` realizado pelo `idHTTP`.

Comment: Poderia postar o que você já tem? assim ficaria mais fácil ajudarmos.

Comment: eu tenho um query com uns 10.000 registros, o que faço é percorrer ela e fazer um post com o idHttp;
....basicamente;

while not qryRegistros.eof do
   begin
     
     //monto json com os registros
     //chamo o metodo post

      postJSON(JSON); 
     qryRegistros.next;
   end;

Comment: Ok, se você limitar a quantidade de registros retornados pela sua query, não resolve o problema?

Comment: creio que não, já que tenho que gerar o json de todos e mandar, então o plano seria colocar em um pool de thread para ir processando....

Comment: Certo, mas a cada execução da Thread você quer executar 10 registros da sua Query, correto?

Comment: seria mandar 10 registros para 10 threads, aguardar e assim que ir concluindo mandar as proximas....

Comment: Entendi, me passa o código dessa sua query, assim eu utilizo ela mesmo para fazer a listagem.

Comment: ela é simples, eu tenho o campo com o json, então só passo ela no post....

<code>
with query.eof do
  begin
  
     postJSON(query.FieldByName('JSON').asString)); 
    
 query.next; 
  end;
</code>

Comment: Qual versão do Delphi você esta utilizando?

Comment: uso o Delphi berlin

Comment: Como você esta passando uma estrutura muito superficial, só vou conseguir te ajudar superficialmente também, dentro do Form1 você tem a variável thread, essa variável seria a que coloquei no meu código *MinhasThreads: Array of MinhaThread;*. e sua consulta deveria estar dentro do form1 e para cada 10 registro você criaria uma nova thread dentro da lista, da forma que escrevi na minha resposta abaixo. Depois é só esperar todas as threads terminar a execução.

Comment: como o codigo original faz consulta a banco e utiliza outras classes, eu fiz esse exemplo funcional que se aproxima 100% do processo e problema que tenho, de qualquer forma agradeço a atenção e vou tentar aqui, obrigado.

Comment: Dá uma olhada em http://www.omnithreadlibrary.com/index.htm é um framework que faz thread poll e muito mais! Baixa e olha o exemplo 11_ThreadPool

Answer (score 1):

Veja se este processo ajuda a resolver seu problema:

```
var
  MinhasThreads: Array of MinhaThread;
  i: Integer;
begin

  SetLength(MinhasThreads, 0);

  // Criando as threads dinâmicamente
  for i := 0 to 9 do
    begin
      SetLength(MinhasThreads, Length(MinhasThreads) + 1);
      MinhasThreads[High(MinhasThreads)] := MinhaThread.Create(True);
      MinhasThreads[High(MinhasThreads)].FreeOnTerminate := True;
      MinhasThreads[High(MinhasThreads)].Start;
    end;

  // Verificar se existe alguma Thread em execução
  //O sistema irá ficar rodando esse laço de repetição até que todas as threads sejam finalizadas.
  i := 0;
  while (i <= High(MinhasThreads)) do
    begin
      if (MinhasThreads[i] <> nil) then
        i := 0
      else
        Inc(i);
    end;
end;
```

A ideia é, criar todas as threads dentro de um array, essas threads são configuradas para se auto-destruir assim que o procedimento *execute* for finalizado.

Comment: Poderia me explicar alguns trechos do codigo, pois no SetLength.. qual sua função ?
o for será o while dos meus registros ?

Comment: SetLength é responsável por setar o tamanho do array, ou seja, quantas posições ele terá. O for seria sim seu while, e a cada loop a função SetLength adiciona uma posição no array. Assim podemos ter uma quantidade indeterminada de threads executando.

Comment: ok, e onde irei setar o metodo de execute, hoje eu uso a thread dessa maneira ....

``

Comment: O seu procedimento execute será acionado nesta linha: *MinhasThreads[High(MinhasThreads)].Start;*
No Create da Thread passamos True, ou seja, ela será criada mas não executada. Então só executará quando dermos o Start.

Comment: ok, e onde irei setar o metodo de execute, hoje eu uso a thread dessa maneira ....
`....
procedure MinhaThread.Execute;
Var Sender : TObject;
begin
   synchronize(Verifica);
   frmProcessos.consultaProcesso(Sender); 

   while not Terminated do
    begin
        Sleep (10);
        Terminate; // Finaliza a Thread
        synchronize(Fechar);
    end;

end;
`
Hoje usa a Thread...o consulta Processo é query que percorro, não identifiquei como eu iria mandar 10, esperar o retorno e ir mandando na medida que for liberando....

Comment: Este exemplo que você passou esta muito superficial, faz assim, edita sua pergunta e coloca la todo o código da sua thread, e o código de onde você chama a thread.

Comment: Ok, montei um exemplo de como estou fazendo, creio que agora seja mais facil entender meu sofrimento.

Comment: conseguiu entender o exemplo que montei ? estou precisando muito adaptar esse processo, pois 18.000 registros ficou mais de 18hs rodando no metodo atual.